# Как закрыть приложение по возврату из дочерней activity

Tags: java, android

В приложении есть 2 активити - auth и dialogs. Пытаюсь запретить юзеру возврат из dialogs в auth. Первое что приходит на ум это выход из приложения по нажатию кнопки back(на нижней панели). Использую такой код:

```
 public void onDestroy() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    super.onDestroy();
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Есть 2 проблемы:

1)При нажатии back предыдущая activity всё-таки появляется на мгновение,  и только потом приложение закрывается.

2)Читал на форумах что использование System.exit(0); не рекомендуется, но альтернативы не нашёл.

Помогите разобраться с ситуацией.

Answer (score 5):

При переходе в активити исользуйте флаги для очистки стека активити.

```
Intent main = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(main);
```

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего, вам надо завершать auth при открытии dialog. Выглядит это как-то так:

```
Intent main = new Intent(auth.this, dialog.class);
auth.this.startActivity(main)
auth.this.finish();
```